# How to click on element using xpath in selenium webdriver?(Usually it works for me , but dont works for this specific url)

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to click on an input field in the [Website-link](https://www.kayak.com/flights)  using `xpath`
usually it works for me for all urls.. but for this specific url whatever I try I cant click on the input field using `selenium webdriver`.

Webdriver loads the page but won't click on the element.
This is what I have tried so far: *(it is a java project for test automation using Selenium webdriver)*

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\nimal\\eclipse-workspace\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe") ;
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
       driver.get("https://www.kayak.com/flights");

       WebElement searchfield1 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='c5NwV-origin-airport-display']")); 
       searchfield1.click();
       WebElement searchfield2 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='c5NwV-origin-airport']")); 
       searchfield2.sendKeys("Toronto");
```

I tried to first click on the `div element` using `xpath`, as then only I get the input field.
Then tried to send "Toronto" to the input field using `xpath`.

Any help or suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Your locator `//*[@id='c5NwV-origin-airport']` returns no matches whereas `//*[contains(@id,'-origin-airport')]`returns 16 matches.  Which one are you trying to sendkeys to?

Comment: Likewise `//*[@id='c5NwV-origin-airport-display']` returns no matches for me.  This is apparently a dynamically created ID and you'll need to narrow down the locator using additional information.

Comment: @Bill Hileman This is the first time i am dealing with Dynamic IDs, and Thanks for the help.This is what exactly i was looking for.

Comment: @Bill Hileman, It clicks properly when i select the first of the 16 possibilties, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the id is getting changed dynamically.So, you need to find the element using other unqiue reference and you need to change your Xpath locator for the `searchfield1` as `//div[@class='search-form-inner']//div[@data-placeholder='From?'`]

`searchfield2` element can be find using the name attribute. you need to perform clear action before sending the key.Since,some of the data is pre populated in the origin field

As a best practice add some wait after loading the URL for the page load completion.

**Working Code:**

```
driver.get("https://www.kayak.com/flights");

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Flights"));

WebElement searchfield1 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='search-form-inner']//div[@data-placeholder='From?']"));
searchfield1.click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("origin")));

WebElement searchfield2 =  driver.findElement(By.name("origin"));
searchfield2.clear();
searchfield2.sendKeys("Toronto");
```

Comment: @Nimalkrishna: Glad to know that it helped!